# Remove CSS property added by insertRule()

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added CSS with `insertRule`. Now I would like to remove the property `background` after 1 second, to make it be the way it was before (set by Bootstrap).

```js
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
    .mt-preview .panel-heading {                
        background: yellowgreen !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        transition: all 0.75s;
    }
`, css.cssRules.length);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.mt-preview .panel-heading').style.removeProperty('background');
}, 1000);
```

I have used `removeProperty()` but that seems not to work. How can I remove that property?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7j3vbk6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`deleteRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule) also from CSSStyleSheet, you just need to know which index is the rule you want to remove.

```js
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
    .mt-preview .panel-heading {                
        background: yellowgreen !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        transition: all 0.75s;
    }
`, css.cssRules.length);

setTimeout(() => css.deleteRule(0), 1000) // use 10 in your JSFiddle
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-group mt-preview">
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading"><strong>My title</strong></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="mt-preview-info">My text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### UPDATE - based on OP comment

> Well, but that removes the whole CSS but I want to remove the property background only.

You can use `style` from `ElementCSSInlineStyle.style`, something like this:

```js
const heading = document.querySelector('.mt-preview .panel-heading')

heading.style = 'background: yellowgreen; color: #fff; transition: all 0.75s;'

//or
//heading.style.cssText = 'background: yellowgreen; color: #fff; transition: all 0.75s;'

//or
//heading.setAttribute('style', 'background: yellowgreen; color: #fff; transition: all 0.75s;')

setTimeout(() => heading.style.removeProperty('background'), 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel-group mt-preview">
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading"><strong>My title</strong></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="mt-preview-info">My text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, but that removes the whole CSS but I want to remove the property `background` only.

Comment: Ok, I knew how to remove it when using `style` but I was just wondering if the property can be removed when using `insertRule()` but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deleteRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule). Whenever you add the rule via insertRule, it will return the index at which the property has been added. You can use the same index to remove the property via deleteRule.

```
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
const index = css.insertRule(`
    .mt-preview .panel-heading {                
        background: yellowgreen !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        transition: all 0.75s;
    }
`, css.cssRules.length);

setTimeout(() => {
 css.deleteRule(index)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Same answer as mine 10 minutes after, why?

Comment: Just because you haven't explained the rule, nothing else

Comment: The explanation is in the link I've added. no need to add the same answer